# Multiprocessing with Python?

Tags: python, python-multiprocessing

How do I write a program that allows me to have an interactive chat session? It forwards `stdin` to some other process, shows the output, and then waits for more user input? I want the communication to be in real time as well.

I was thinking that I use an infinite loop and import the `sys` module and use the `sys.stdin.readline()` function and `sys.stdout.write()` function. I am currently confused on how to implement multiprocessing into my code.

Comment: For interactive chat from the terminal, I'd look into sockets module and client-server programming model, not multiprocessing. Hope this helps.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`multiprocessing` is just a module that allows you to create another process to execute your target function. The parameters and results can be transferred by giving a pipeline and you need to implement a reader/writer processes to observe the pipe line for incoming outputs and send necessary parameters.

https://docs.python.org/2/library/multiprocessing.html should give you enough information to get yourself started.

What you must know is, compared to `threading` module, `multiprocessing` is creating a true process, instead of a thread in the current process. So one big difference is the performance. Python has a GIL(global interpreter lock), so threading will be blocked by GIL time to time, and performance is impacted so. If you don't care performance, `threading` will be a choice as well. both of their functions are quite similar, but you have to understand thread and process first before you use either of the module, otherwise you may have weird issues while handling the pipelines.

By the way, I strongly recommend you to take a look at `rpyc` module, it will save A LOT of time for you. It is a python RPC module, allows you to send messages among machines, with very simple APIs, and you don't have to worry about the pipelines.